# Will my work experience from a company will be considered without an explicit experience letter?

Tags: job-change, work-experience, india, employment, documentation

I worked at a company for 1.5 years, I followed each term and condition as I was fresher that time and I hadn't more knowledge about How IT sector works regarding documentation.

I had given a proper notice period of 2 months worked till the last date. On my last day, I met my boss to say thank you. He told me that he will send me my salary and all letter on 5-December-2018.  I believed in him and I joined a new company after one month when I haven't got any calls or salary or any letter then I went to the office after talking and asking why this is being delayed. Then they give me salary and clearance letter and also mention that I have resigned from there employment and getting  released from my duties after 30th Nov 2018 after 7 pm, and told me that they will give experience letter after looking at all the work that I did because they are busy,but again its been 5 months and i haven't got my experience letter.

Here is what I have from the First company

1. Offer letter
2. every month's salary credited in my salary accounts so I have the bank
   E-slip,
3. Email regarding notice period and my last date of working,
4. Email with my clearance  letter in soft copy,
5. emails regarding salary delay

Here what I am getting from my current company

1. Offer letter
2. every month salary credited in my salary accounts so  I have the bank
   E-slip,
3. they also send me salary slip every month

Will my experience year from first company counts in future?

Comment: You really need to get rid of all that unnecessary details.

Comment: I changed the title of your question, feel free to revert if you have objections.

Comment: Depending on your locality I think there is often a legal right to get a testimony. However the question is if it is worth the trouble. If you put a job experience in your CV it’s often considered without further questions, especially if it’s a low profile short entry level job. And you can always answer in the job interview that they failed to provide proper documentation yet.

Comment: I tagged this India, because many concepts you mention seem to be specific to that country and *only apply in India*. Feel free to change the tags again if I'm wrong.

Comment: it's fine and a valid tag

Answer (score 5):

> *Will my experience Year from first company counts in future?*

Yes, given the list of document you posses, (specifically, email for last working day and the clearance letter) you can prove that you worked for them, and it will be counted towards your total experience.

Comment: thanks, Sourav but I am worried because of my colleagues said that in future I may face problem during verification without experience letter

Comment: @ArunPratap I don't get it...you have joining letter, you have clearance (relieving) letter...that itself states the experience, is not it? Or, are you talking about domain-specific experience in particular - in which case it's more of a testimonial, usually of no value in an interview.

Comment: if offer letter and clearance letter and as you said that itself states the experience then thanks you solved my headache

Answer (score 2):

Experience always counts. Most of the time you will be trusted, but even the smallest of the proofs that you worked somehwere will be taken into account. A company is (sometimes) not a bureaucracy, so they couldn't care less about what papers you can show them.

Comment: thanks,  David I have everything apart from experience letter even I know every part of the projects that I have done there

Comment: @ArunPratap Then of course it will count!